# Where do files rsynced to a host go?

Tags: search, rsync, restore

I accidentally rsynced `.thunderbird` to `user@host` instead of to `user@host:/home/user`.

Where is `.thunderbird` now?  Is there a good way to search for the folder?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's in the directory where you ran the command:

```
$ touch foo
$ ls -l foo bar@baz
ls: cannot access 'bar@baz': No such file or directory
-rw-rw-r-- 1 muru muru 0 May 30 16:53 foo
$ rsync -aP foo bar@baz
sending incremental file list
foo
              0 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)
$ ls -l foo bar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 muru muru 0 May 30 16:53 bar@baz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 muru muru 0 May 30 16:53 foo
```

If you did `rsync .thunderbird user@host:` and not `rsync .thunderbird user@host` (note the `:`), then the directory was copied to the home directory of `user` on `host` (so `/home/user` would usually be redundant in `user@host:/home/user`). Without the `:`, the second argument is just the path to a target directory on the local system.

The same applies to `scp`.

Note that `rsync` does not delete source files unless you tell it to. So `.thunderbird` is still where it was, and a new copy is made wherever it was copied to.

Also note that `rsync` has different behaviour based on whether the source directory had a trailing `/`. These two are different:

```
rsync -aP .thunderbird somewhere
rsync -aP .thunderbird/ somewhere
```

In the first case, the `.thunderbird` directory is copied `somewhere`, but in the second case, the *contents* of `.thunderbird` are copied (so you won't see `somewhere/.thunderbird`, but if there was a `.thunderbird/foo`, you'd see `somewhere/foo` instead of `somewhere/.thunderbird/foo`).

Comment: Sigh. *removes answer I was about to post*

Comment: @Ole `user@host` maybe a different laptop, but without `:`, `rsync` treats it as a name for the local system. What command did you run, **exactly**?

Comment: So I ran rsync -vaz .thunderbird ole@192.168.1.2

Comment: The files finished, but they are not in /home/ole/.thunderbird ... so now I'm wondering where .thunderbird went ... :)

Comment: @Ole see notes about `:` and `/`  above - did you use `.thunderbird/` or `.thunderbird`, and `ole@192.168.1.2` or `ole@192.168.1.2:`?

Comment: .thunderbird and ole@192.168.1.2

Comment: Then `.thunderbird` was copied to a directory named `ole@192.168.1.2` in whichever directory you ran the command.

Comment: HA!  OK that explains why I was seeing that in nautilus!  Thanks - You rock!!!  3 am here.  Now I can finally hit the sack.

Comment: So you actually _saw_ with your own eyes where it ended up but asked anyway lol. Praps next time sleep on the problem.